# Const C-String on Stack?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const char* s = nullptr;
    {
        s = "inner";
    }
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Where is "inner" stored in the memory?

Valgrind doesn't complain.  Is it stored in the data segment?

Thanks.

Comment: Most likely rodata or equivalent, but that sort of thing is *highly* platform-dependent. The C++ standard cares only that it has static storage duration. What platform are you using?

Comment: @Bregalad this is a C++ question. Also there are cases where an array does not decay to a pointer in both languages, for example when it is the operand of `&` or `sizeof` .

Comment: Only the pointer `s` is on the stack. The string it points to `"inner"` could be anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard

> 8 Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred
>   to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal has type “array
>   of n const char”, where n is the size of the string as defined below,
>   and **has static storage duration** (3.7).

So though the string literal in your porgram is used in inner block of main

```
{
    s = "inner";
}
```

it is alive until the program finished its execution and all memory of the process will be freed.

Usually string literals are placed in a read-only data segment.

Answer (score 1):

It is similar to:

```
static const char t[] = "inner";

s = t;
```

So, consult your implementation's documentation for what it does with `static const` data. On some implementations this is `.text` or `.rodata` . Some implementations may store string literals in a different area than other static const data.

Answer (score 1):

> Valgrind doesn't complain.

That's because there is nothing wrong with your code: `s` remains in scope. Curly braces around the place where you assign a constant value to `s` have no effect on your program's flow, because they do not contain declarations.

> Where is "inner" stored in the memory?

The answer is platform-dependent. It is usually stored along with your program's code, but there are platforms where string constants must be copied into a different block of memory before being used (e.g. on hardware that uses *Harvard architecture*, which keeps programs and data in separate address spaces).

In any event, the memory allocated to string literals does not get reclaimed until your program's end.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a simple test: try some `strcpy` to write on the const string memory.

most likely you'll have segmentation fault on Linux.

Therefore for sure it doesn't located on the stack and not on a data segment.
what left is the code segments, or other read only segment, which is the obvious answer.

if you want to know for sure, generate **map file** by giving to gcc the link flag as follows:

`-Wl,-Map=output.map`

there you can see exactly where the const string was stored.